Separate Index Download for Android Nougat
I have slow internet connectivity and my Android Studio version Koala takes time to update indexes while I am working. So I wonder, is there a way I could get a separate Index Download for it and update it later on offline?
I am creating an app but indexing takes too long while working, preventing me to work fast.

Indexing is usually performed locally by the CPU. Normally there is no download involved. And once everything has been downloaded and the project is in sync there shouldn't be su much index updates anymore. May be you misinterpret that indexing and downloading happen at the same time in independent jobs?
